# Query to determine if a JSON value contains a specified attribute

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I want to query a table that has JSON data. The data of the column **detail** in the table **details** are as follows.

```
id     | 1

detail | {
   myCompany: [{ email: 'company@company.com', inProfit: true }],
   myData: [
      { email: 'example@example.com', personalUse: true },
      { email: 'test@test.com', personalUse: false },
   ],
};
```

The **JSON** value of the column **detail** is as follows

```
{
   "myCompany":[
      {
         "email":"company@company.com",
         "inProfit":true
      }
   ],
   "myData":[
      {
         "email":"example@example.com",
         "personalUse":true
      },
      {
         "email":"test@test.com",
         "personalUse":false
      }
   ]
}
```

I want a query that fetches **id** if the passed **email** is present in **myData** and has **true** value for **personalUse**. The query doesn't return any **id** if the passed email is present but doesn't have **personalUse** as **true**.

I have used the below two queries but it will return **id** for both cases.

```
SELECT id 
FROM details 
WHERE (detail->'myData')::JSONB @> '[{"email": "example@example.com"}, 
                                     {"personalUse": true}]'::JSONB;

SELECT id 
FROM details 
WHERE (detail->'myData')::JSONB @> '[{"email": "test@test.com"}, 
                                     {"personalUse": true}]'::JSONB;
```

Expected output is it should return **id** for first query and not return any **id** for second one.

You can use the below queries to try it locally.

```
CREATE TABLE details (id bigserial primary key, detail json not null);

INSERT INTO details (detail) 
VALUES 
  ('{"myCompany":[{"email":"company@company.com", "inProfit":true } ],  
     "myData":[{"email":"example@example.com", "personalUse":true }, 
               {"email":"test@test.com", "personalUse":false } ] }');
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: if you declare the column as `jsonb` you can get rid of all the casting

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for your help with this. I am struck once again. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386815/query-to-update-the-json-that-does-not-contain-a-specific-key and hope you will find the solution for this. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing an array with two elements (each with one key) in your queries, rather than an array with one element that contains two keys.

The array contains `{"email": "test@test.com", "personalUse": true}` data) and that is something different then 
`{"email": "example@example.com"}, {"personalUse": true}` - which is the value you compare against.

In your queries, the first json key/value pair (with the email address) matches in both values in the table and the contains operator `@>` only checks for at least one match.

The following queries work as expected:

```
SELECT id 
FROM details 
WHERE detail -> 'myData' @> '[{"email": "test@test.com", "personalUse": true}]';

SELECT id 
FROM details 
WHERE detail -> 'myData' @> '[{"email": "example@example.com", "personalUse": true}]';
```

(I removed the casts to `jsonb` for better readability)

Comment: hi, @a-horse-with-no-name I need another help. For the above data some records in `myData` only have email, not `personalUse` field. Now I want a query that returns the email which doesn't have `personalUse` field. Please help me out.